# What is LinkedListNode in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Excuse my ignorance but I am beginning to prepare for my first technical interview and came across this question and answer on the topic linkedlist

**Question: Implement an algorithm to delete a node in the middle of a single linked list, given only access to that node**

```
public static boolean deleteNode(LinkedListNode n) {
if (n == null || n.next == null) {
   return false; // Failure
}
LinkedListNode next = n.next;
n.data = next.data;
n.next = next.next;
return true;
}
```

I want to start playing with this code (making changes compile test) but I'm not sure how to start doing this in Java. I cannot find the LinkedListNode class in Java docs.

This might be a very silly question but if someone can point me in the right direction - will appreciate it.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the quick and useful responses. I guess my question was not very clear. The algorithm above was provided as a solution to that question. I wanted to know how to implement that in Java so I can play around with the code.

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code will only work properly if there's a tail node on the list.

The algorithm works with the following logic

```
When referring to the node to be deleted, call it "curr"
When referring to the node before "curr", call it "prev"
When referring to the node after "curr", call it "next"

To effectively delete our node, "prev".next should point to "next"
It currently points to "curr"

Our problem is that we have no reference to "prev"

We know "prev".next points to "curr"

Since we cannot change the fact that "prev".next points to "curr",
we must have "curr" gobble up "next"

We make "curr"s data be "next"s data
We make "curr"s next be "next"s next

The reason this only works if there's a tail guard 
is so we can make "next" be the "tail" node of the 
list. (Its data is null and it's next is null.) Otherwise, 
"prev".next would still be pointing to something.
```

Here's a class that uses LinkedListNode. I should note that if you're applying for a position as a programmer, you should be able to do this basically from memory. :-)

```
class LinkedList<E> {

    static class LinkedListNode<E> {
        E data;
        LinkedListNode<E> next;
    }

    /**
     * Not exactly the best object orientation, but we'll manage
     */
    static <E> E deleteNode(LinkedListNode<E> node) {
        if(node == null || node.next == null) return null;

        E retval = node.data;
        LinkedListNode<E> next = node.next;
        node.data = next.data;
        node.next = next.next;
        return retval;
    }

    private LinkedListNode<E> head;
    private LinkedListNode<E> tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = new LinkedListNode<E>();
        this.tail = new LinkedListNode<E>();
        head.next = tail;
    }

    public void addLast(E e) {
        LinkedListNode<E> node = new LinkedListNode<E>(); // e and next are null
        tail.data = e;
        tail.next = node;
        tail = node;
    }

    public void addFirst(E e) {
        LinkedListNode<E> node = new LinkedListNode<E>(); // e and next are null;
        node.next = head.next;
        node.data = e;
        head.next = node;
    }

    public E deleteFirst() {
        LinkedListNode<E> first = head.next;
        head.next = first.next;
        return first.data;
    }

    public E deleteLast() {
        // cannot do without iteration of the list! :-(
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public LinkedListNode<E> findFirst(E e) {
        LinkedListNode<E> curr = head.next;
        while(curr != null) {
            if(curr.data != null && curr.data.equals(e)) return curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void print() {
        LinkedListNode<E> curr = head.next;
        while(curr.next != null) {
            System.out.println(curr.data);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.addLast("Apple");
        list.addLast("Bear");
        list.addLast("Chair");
        list.addLast("Dirt");

        //list.print();

        LinkedListNode<String> bear = list.findFirst("Bear");
        deleteNode(bear);

        list.print();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for clearly explaining on how this works. So I wanted to know how I would implement this in java.

Comment: @Riamo what do you mean? You've already listed the code that implements this.

Comment: @glowcoder - Thanks - that code does not work - like LinkedListNode is not a class in java sdk

Comment: yeah, and so you add your own class like this

Comment: @Riamo just posted an example that should help you out.

Comment: @glowcoder - Thanks a lot man - this is what I was looking for. thanks for your time. Yes I'm a good 6 months away from applying as a programmer - so getting a head start preparing for interviews. Thumbs up !!!!

Comment: @riamo I'm going to be honest with you. I'm not saying it to be mean, I just want you to do well. For a 4 year computer-science degree, people are expected to be able to do this at about 2 years in. So you may have some catching up to do. And that's *fine* really it is. Just have to go forward with the right attitude. Learn all you can and focus on solving problems ahead of writing code. (Once the problem is solved, the code follows.) If you want a good example of a problem to solve, take the LinkedList and LinkedListNode I just wrote and make it doubly linked. :-)

Comment: I am a beginner in Java, would you be so kind as to explain what <E> and other use of E in your code is and does? Would you give a reference to its general usage if it is convenient for you?

Comment: `<E>` is a *generic type*. It can be any type. When you use something like `ArrayList<String>` that was defined in the code as `ArrayList<E>` (well it might be T, the actual letter doesn't matter...) so that it would work with all types.

Comment: Thank you, corsiKa. Could you further explain in the code in Gubloo's answer below, what "Object" which seems to declare some property, supposedly not "type", of "data"? Does "Object" serve as some kind of "wild card" type so that it is not necessary to declare type beforehand?

Comment: Gubloo's answer uses `Object` instead of a generic type. Consider `ArrayList<String>` for a moment: it will only accept `String` objects. His container will accept any `Object`. (It's worth noting that the generics only matter during compiling - my class will turn into `Object` instead of `E` in the bytecode, but generics won't compile if you try to add an invalid object, so you detect your bug much faster.) It sounds like you need a good tutorial on generics!! :-)

Comment: The `head` and `tail` objects are sentinel nodes. If I was hardening this class for production use (because for some reason I couldn't use the built in api? I dunno) those fields would be final.

Comment: What does the <> mean when you defined the LinkedNode class?

Comment: @Amad27 I'm not sure what you mean. I don't see an empty `<>` anywhere in the answer. Could you be more specific about the line of code in question?

Comment: Apologies @corsiKa. I meant, what does `<E>` mean? I see it everywhere eg, the declaration of `LinkedListNode<E>` ?

Comment: The topmost class is defined as `class LinkedList<E>` - this means "When we make a `LinkedList<String>`, all the `E` become `String`. (That's not  100% correct, but it's easy enough to grasp.) Now, because `LinkedListNode<E>` is inside `LinkedList<E>`, then the node class will also use the same E, which means a `LinkedList<String>` will create child classes of `LinkedListNode<String>` - we design the class to accept any type of object at declaration.

Comment: The implementation of deleteLast and deleteNode in this are completely wrong.

Comment: @adamjk well, `deleteLast` isn't implemented because it's a single linked list... so I fail to see how, not being implemented, it could be wrong at all. And maybe it's the wine I've already had, but I don't see the problem with `deleteNode` - but maybe you should be helpful and say what is wrong about it instead of the smug "drive by criticism" you've displayed.

Answer (score 6):

This class is most likely a hypothetical class used for this [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) example question.

Comment: Yeah thats what I figured. So is there is any simple example to implement this algorithm in java

Answer (score 6):

LinkedListNode is a class that you will define to hold data. To get your above example to work - I've quickly written this code (just to make you understand the simple concept) in which I am creating 3 nodes (which are linked to each other) and then deleting the middle one calling the *deleteNode* method that you have specified in your question.

The code is pretty self explanatory. Let me know if this helps.
Good Luck

```
class LinkedListNode
{
    public Object data;
    public LinkedListNode next;

    public LinkedListNode(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
    }
}

class DeleteNodeLinkedList
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        LinkedListNode node_1 = new LinkedListNode("first");        
        LinkedListNode node_2 = new LinkedListNode("second");
        node_1.next = node_2;
        LinkedListNode node_3 = new LinkedListNode("third");
        node_2.next = node_3;

        System.out.println("*** Print contents of linked list");
        LinkedListNode  current = node_1;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }

        System.out.println("*** Now delete second node");
        deleteNode(node_2);

        System.out.println("*** Print after deleting second node");
        current = node_1;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteNode(LinkedListNode n) 
    {
        if (n == null || n.next == null) {
            return false; // Failure
        }
        LinkedListNode next = n.next;
        n.data = next.data;
        n.next = next.next;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The important details in this question pertain to data structures, java is just the language that is being used to implement in this case.
You should read the wikipedia article about [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), and for this question be careful that your solution doesn't produce any **dangling references** or **orphan nodes**.
Do some searches on the two terms in bold, and make sure that you understand them

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit confusing. whether you want a logic to remove a node in a singly linkedlist or you want to learn and use java LinkedlistNode.

if you are in second the following link will help you

[LinkedListNodee](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/util/LinkedListNode.html)

or if you want the logic

```
let P the pointer to the current node
P->data = P->next->data
Q=P->next
P->next=Q->next
delete(Q)
```