# When to use LinkedListNode vs LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm having trouble understanding this problem from cracking the coding interview:

*Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list*

**Solution:**

```
 public static void deleteDups(LinkedListNode n){
    Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
    LinkedListNode previous = null; 
    while(n != null ){
        if(table.containsKey(n.data)) {
            previous.next = n.next;
        } else{
            table.put(n.data, true);
            previous = n;
        }
        n = n.next;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why you pass in a LinkedListNode rather than a LinkedList. If you want to delete dups from a linkedlist why wouldn't you just take in and iterate through the whole list?

Comment: Assuming `n` is the head of the list, there's no difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is LinkedListNode in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374077/what-is-linkedlistnode-in-java)

Comment: Passing a node instead of the entire list allows the user to define a starting point (the node to start at), instead of doing the entire list. I don't know if that is needed somewhere. If not, then there is no big difference.

Comment: Not a duplicate, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name suggest its a `LinkedList`, so if you have the starting Node, you have the list. `LinkedList` is mere chain of different Nodes in different memory spaces, do not treat or expect it to be like array, which is a continuous chunk of space.

Answer (score 2):

Here LinkedListNode is a class as

```
    public LinkedListNode{
    int data;
    LinkedListNode next;

    public LinkedListNode(int data){
    this.data = data;
    next = null;
    }

    }
    LinkedListNode head = new LinkedListNode(1);
    LinkedListNode node1 = new LinkedListNode(2);
    LinkedListNode node2 = new LinkedListNode(3);
    head.next = node1;
    node1.next  = node2;
    //1->2-3
    deleteDups(head);
```

here `head` node(data =1) is the head of created linked list which we are passing in deleteDups.
In this function we are iterating over the give list using next.

Comment: Another consideration is that such a de-duplicator could be used, say, in "tree or tree-like" situations, where you might somehow be using *recursion.* However, it really is a fairly-arbitrary decision. You could correctly write this function either way.